# YouTube upload via website using google API for ASP.net and showing progress

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, youtube, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I have been trying to use the Google API to upload videos from a website (using OAuth2 for authentication to our business YouTube account) which works great but I need to be able to show the progress of that upload and when it completes etc

I am using the code sample found here: https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client-samples/blob/master/ResumableUpload.VB.Sample/ResumeableUploadSample.vb

As you can see its an Async call to the upload which works fine, the issue I have is not being able to show the progress on the page and when the upload is finished or has an error.

Is this possible via an Async call as its beyond my knowledge and if not what code can I use instead?

The users of the site will have their own login but the videos will be uploaded to our YouTube account via OAuth2 authentication.

I have googled this for over 3 days trying different scenarios with no luck whatsoever.

Any help or pointers would be gratefully appreciated.
Thanks,
Gary

Answer (score 0):

In the sample, the method **VideoInsertRequest_ProgressChanged()** displays progress and completion status. Make sure you have executed the **AddHandler()** method to enable **VideoInsertRequest_ProgressChanged()**. See Line 136.

Likewise, the method **VideoInsertRequest_ResponseReceived()** is enabled by an **AddHandler()** call so it can display the **videoResource.Id** returned by YouTube. See Line 137.

Comment: Mike, many thanks for the response. The code works fine, the issue is that I do not know how to get the Console.writeline info, on to a webpage.

Comment: Ideally, in realtime to show the status of the upload as well as it being completed.